# Track image clicks with links on Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm trying to get a thing work for a week and no success. Really need some tips.
I have an Wordpress website built with Elementor.

This site has 10 different images with different links (they are links to stores that sell my product).

I'm trying to do something automatic in GTM that when I click on one of the stores (image with link), it shows me the variable - that is, the name of the store - that I added as an attribute in Elementor.

My question is whether it's possible to make this variable value show automatically so I don't have to create 10 different tags. I say this because I have 5 more sites in the same type of construction that I imagine I will have to do manually.

I followed this example and it almost worked - : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MUyJeRDKt0kThe problem is that he has a class naming, but I don't. I have only link attribute.

Something like this:
Product > Sells in Walgreens, Walmart, Costco, etc .
Attribute name and value:clickstore - wallgreensclickstore - Walmartetc.
Why I'm trying to do that? To mark as a conversion in GA4.
Any tips?Thanks a lot!

@BNazaruk
please se the image of the html[image]

The tag fired, but doesn't populate the values automaticcaly!
[image]

Comment: Show your html. Also show how your `Click Element` variable looks like in GTM preview on the image click.

Comment: @BNazaruk here's the image of the HTML. Please notice the attribute "cliquefarma1"

Comment: Please have your html as text, so that I could copy it and test the selector. Also, you've made a screenshot of a tag in the debugger. I asked for a photo of the variable, not tag. The click element variable in the variables tab. Make sure you do it on the click event. Just to see what element the click really lands on.

Comment: Following the previous comment: [Here's why you shouldn't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Please edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

@BNazaruk, sorry about the delay.
Please see below :)
That's an example with 2 stores.
Thanks a lot for the support!

```
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-6511396 e-container--column e-container" data-id="6511396" data-element_type="container">               <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-4ea1df3 elementor-widget elementor-widget-image" data-id="4ea1df3" data-element_type="widget" cliquefarma="Store1" data-widget_type="image.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                <div class="elementor-image">
                                                    <a href="link for store 1" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener" cliquefarma1="Store1">
                            <img decoding="async" width="220" height="157" src="storeimage1.jpg" class="attachment-large size-large" alt="" loading="lazy" />                               </a>
                                                        </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div><div class="elementor-element elementor-element-715f6ca e-container--column e-container" data-id="715f6ca" data-element_type="container">             <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-92cd80b elementor-widget elementor-widget-image" data-id="92cd80b" data-element_type="widget" id="cfarmacia1" cliquefarma="Store 2" data-widget_type="image.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                <div class="elementor-image">
                                                    <a href="store 2 link" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener" cliquefarma1="Store 2">
                            <img decoding="async" width="220" height="157" src="storeimage2.jpg" class="attachment-large size-large" alt="" loading="lazy" />                               </a>
                                                        </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
```